# ComboBox databinding to window background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Very new to `WPF` and `c#` here. I'm interested in having a `ComboBox` with different color options that will update the window's `Background` when an option is selected.

I want to do this via `DataBinding`, but I'm a noob and can't get it right. This is what I have.

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        Background="{Binding SelectedValue,ElementName=combo,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="combo">
            <ComboBoxItem>lightcoral</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>khaki</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the default `MainWindow.xaml.cs` (I haven't touched it since I created the project)

Thanks, let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: You can find some explanation and examples at [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this is to put items of type `string` in your ComboBox, as opposed to `ComboBoxItem`s:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Background="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=combo}">
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="combo">
        <sys:String>Yellow</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Green</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Red</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
    </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

- Notice that I declared the `xmlns:sys` [XAML Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx) that points to the `System` CLR namespace in the mscorlib.dll assembly. This is where the class `System.String` is defined, and you need that to be able to use the class in XAML.
- Also notice that I'm binding to `SelectedItem` as opposed to `SelectedValue`, this is because your ComboBox does not have `SelectedValuePath`, and WPF doesn't have the notion of the `SelectedValue` because it does not know how to "retrieve the value" from each of it's items.
- Also notice that `UpdateSourceTrigger` is removed because it does not make any sense. `UpdateSourceTrigger` determines the way the Binding *source* is updated, not the *target*. Read about [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN to understand the terminology here.
- The reason that using a `String` works and using a `ComboBoxItem` does not is because the default [Type Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy580hbd.aspx) for the `Brush` class (which is the type of the Window's Background) "understands" how to convert from a `string`, but not from a `ComboBoxItem`.